# PHPMailer very slow sending email

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have an application sending email with PHPMailer on PHP 7.2, I have to send around 50 emails and it takes about 40 seconds to complete, which I consider is a lot since according to the documentation it can send up to 300 emails in a second... I have tried with both local email server and Google SMTP service (which is what we need, since it will use a GSuite email as the sender). The function receives an array with the data needed of each customer, but I create the smtp object and it's configuration outside of the loop, the only method that executes once for each customer it's the send(), and if I comment that line, it takes less than 1 second to complete, so the connection is not delaying the execution, it is the send() itself. Is there anyting that I'm doing incorrectly? I dont have a lot of experience with this library and this is based on the basic example, so I'm not sure if there is any configuration I can add or change to speed this up.

```php
public static function ejecutarEnvio($datosCorreo) {
    try {
      $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

      // Configuración general
      $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;      
      $mail->isSMTP();
      $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
      $mail->Host = $_SESSION["smtp_host"];
      $mail->Username = $_SESSION["smtp_user"];
      $mail->Password = $_SESSION["smtp_pass"];
      $mail->Port = $_SESSION["smtp_port"];
      if ($_SESSION["smtp_secure"]=="TLS")
        $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
      elseif ($_SESSION["smtp_secure"]=="SSL")
        $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;
      $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
      $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
      $mail->isHTML(true);
      $mail->setFrom($_SESSION["no_reply"], $_SESSION["no_reply_name"]);

      // envío independiente
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($datosCorreo); $i++) {
        $datos = $datosCorreo[$i];

        // se cargan todas las variables que pueden cambiar en el arreglo de objetos para enviar correo
        if(filter_var(trim($datos['destinatario1']), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
          $mail->addAddress(trim($datos['destinatario1']));
        if(filter_var(trim($datos['destinatario2']), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
          $mail->addCC(trim($datos['destinatario2']));
        if(filter_var(trim($datos['destinatario3']), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
          $mail->addCC(trim($datos['destinatario3']));
        $mail->addReplyTo($datos['replyto']);
        $mail->Subject = $datos['titulo'];
        $mail->Body = $datos['mensaje'];
        // se cargan todas las variables que pueden cambiar en el arreglo de objetos para enviar correo

        try {
          // intento hacer el envio del correo, lo hago dentro de un try independiente para que solo afecte al objeto actual
          if ($mail->send())
            $datosCorreo[$i]['mensaje_correo'] = "";
          else 
            throw new Exception("Error enviando el correo. " . $mail->ErrorInfo);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
          $datosCorreo[$i]['mensaje_correo'] = $e->getMessage();
        }

        $mail->clearAddresses();
      }

      $mail->SmtpClose();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($datosCorreo); $i++) {
        $datosCorreo[$i]['mensaje_correo'] = "Error configurando el envío de correo. " . $e->getMessage();;
      }
    }

    return $datosCorreo;
  }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I doubt you will be able to improve this, since you are dumping the mail off to Google's infrastructure.  Try setting the SMTPDebug to 3 and even 4, and see if anything jumps out at you.  I had to inject my own timing statements on one project where we were having unexplained problems sending mail through a 3rd party MTA.

Comment: Thanks will do, what I dont understand is why with the local mail server it's the same, or even a little bit slower. If it's not possible to solve I think the best approach will be to run the email service via Ajax...

Answer (score 1):

The PHPMailer wiki has extensive [advice on sending to lists](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Sending-to-lists), and there is an example provided which demonstrates [how to send to lists efficiently](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).

The most important thing there is not to create a new instance every time, but to re-use an instance, which allows you to enable SMTP keepalive.

```
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
```

I can see you're doing that here, but there are some other things you can do. When sending via SMTP to localhost, you shouldn't need to use authentication or encryption, so you can disable those:

```
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
$mail->SMTPSecure = false;
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
```

That will eliminate several round-trips.

The reason that it's `send` that takes the time is that PHPMailer hardly does anything up until that point - everything else is setup.

You're validating email addresses inside the loop - `addAddress()` and `addCC` already do this, so you're duplicating effort; check their return values instead and `continue` or ignore if you get a bad address.

This structure is redundant:

```
    try {
      // intento hacer el envio del correo, lo hago dentro de un try independiente para que solo afecte al objeto actual
      if ($mail->send())
        $datosCorreo[$i]['mensaje_correo'] = "";
      else 
        throw new Exception("Error enviando el correo. " . $mail->ErrorInfo);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      $datosCorreo[$i]['mensaje_correo'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
```

You can cut it down to this because you already asked PHPMailer to throw exceptions on error (by passing `true` to the constructor), so it will never reach the point where you throw your own exception:

```
    try {
        $mail->send();
        // intento hacer el envio del correo, lo hago dentro de un try independiente para que solo afecte al objeto actual
        $datosCorreo[$i]['mensaje_correo'] = "";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $datosCorreo[$i]['mensaje_correo'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
```

I have no trouble sending hundreds of messages per second like this, and any decent local mail server should be able to handle thousands of messages per second, so it shouldn't be the cause - but you should check.

To find out where bottlenecks are in any code, I advise using a profiler in an IDE rather than random timing calls; it will tell you immediately where the issue is. xdebug with qcachegrind or PHPStorm works really well for this.